# Reset with while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I have been trying to put a reset to this. So that you can continue forever until you hit enter (blank space) at the movie title selection.

It runs once and not more, can someone help me?

```
package stack;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {

            String temp = input.nextLine();

            if (temp.length() > 0) {
                info in = new info();
                in.setTitel(temp);
                in.filmnamn();

                int nr[] = new int[3];
                int sum = 0;
                System.out.println();

                for (int i = 0; i < nr.length; i++) {
                    System.out.print("Judge " + (i + 1) + " gives the movie: ");
                    nr[i] = input.nextInt();
                    sum += nr[i];
                }
            }
            if (temp.isEmpty())
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the second class:

```
package stack;

public class info {

     private String namn;

     public void setTitel(String film) {

         namn=film;      

     }

     public String getTitel() {

         return namn;
     } 

     public void filmnamn() {
         System.out.printf("Movie title: %s", getTitel());
     }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger? How is the code getting to the break statement? Is temp empty at that point?

Comment: input.nextLine();  // Consume newline left-over. So added this code in the last line of my program and it worked. I do not completly understand the other thread but will read more tomorow. Thank you all for the help <3